# Como utilizar el struct en otros ficheros swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

He creado un struct en un fichero, y me gustaría instanciarlo en otro fichero para utilizar sus datos, pero no sé como hacerlo.

Estoy siguiendo una arquitectura MVVM, entonces el struct lo he creado en el "Model", ahora quiero coger esa estructura y utilizarla en el "ViewModel".

---

Edit:

He creado la siguiente estructura entonces me gustaría ver si lo he hecho bien o no es la manera adecuada de hacerlo:

En el model: HomeGroupModel.swift

```
struct HomeGroup{
    var title: String
}
```

En el viewmodel: HomeGroupViewModel.swift

```
class HomeGroupViewModel{
    let homeGroup: HomeGroup
    init(){
        self.homeGroup = HomeGroup(title: "Estos son los grupos")
    }
}
```

En el viewcontroller de la vista: HomeGroupViewController.swift

```
 class HomeGroupViewController: UIViewController {
     @IBOutlet weak var groupTitle: TitleView!
     var homeGroupViewModel: HomeGroupViewModel!
     override func viewDidLoad(){
         homeGroupViewModel = HomeGroupViewModel()
         groupTitle.setText(text: homeGroupViewModel.homeGroup.title)
     }
 }
```

¿Estaría bien implementado así?

Y si quiero modificar el título desde la vista, ¿debería crear una función de tipo set en el viewmodel?, o ¿con modificarlo directamente en *homeGroupViewModel.homeGroup.title = Lo que quiera* valdría?

Comment: Podrias agregar al menos la cabecera de como declaraste el struct y como lo estas intentando utilizar? eso seria muy util para saber por que no lo estas pudiendo utilizar

Comment: @ErickSilva listo, he modificado el post

Answer (score 0):

Puede cambiar el valor desde la vista modificando el `let` por `var` sin crear el `set`.

```
class HomeGroupViewModel{
    var homeGroup: HomeGroup 
    init(){
        self.homeGroup = HomeGroup(title: "Estos son los grupos")
    }
}
```

En la vista puedes instanciar la clase directamente al declarar la variable:

```
class HomeGroupViewController: UIViewController {
     @IBOutlet weak var groupTitle: TitleView!

     let homeGroupViewModel = HomeGroupViewModel()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         print(homeGroupViewModel.homeGroup.title) //"Estos son los grupos"
         homeGroupViewModel.homeGroup.title = "none"
         print(homeGroupViewModel.homeGroup.title) //"none
     }
 }
```

Comment: El set es una función que cree en una vista, donde hay un label. Entonces lo que hace es modificar el texto de esa label por el que cojo del viewmodel